# mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000)

Tags: python, flask

anyone done this project?
https://github.com/codebasics/python_projects_grocery_webapp

if yes, why this error is occurring - mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '16' for key 'order_details.PRIMARY'

```
from datetime import datetime
from sql_connection import get_sql_connection

def insert_order(connection, order):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    # Insert order
    order_query = ("INSERT INTO orders "
                   "(customer_name, total, datetime)"
                   "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    order_data = (order['customer_name'], order['grand_total'], datetime.now())
    cursor.execute(order_query, order_data)
    order_id = cursor.lastrowid
    
    # Insert order_details
    order_details_query = ("INSERT INTO order_details "
                           "(order_id, product_id, quantity, total_price)"
                           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")

    order_details_data = []
    for order_detail_record in order['order_details']:
        order_details_data.append([
            order_id,
            int(order_detail_record['product_id']),
            float(order_detail_record['quantity']),
            float(order_detail_record['total_price'])
        ])
    cursor.executemany(order_details_query, order_details_data)

    connection.commit()

    return order_id  

if __name__=='__main__':
    connection = get_sql_connection()
    print(insert_order(connection, {
        'customer_name': 'y',
        'grand_total': '500',
        'order_details': [
            {
                'product_id': 11,
                'quantity': 2,
                'total_price': 50
            },
            {
                'product_id': 11,
                'quantity': 1,
                'total_price': 30
            }
        ]
    }))
```

even if i take the source code this error is still occurring

[database ss](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yv6uxeSOfNdbq9TcIdzc8kqbbAZCBOMN)

Comment: "Duplicate entry '16' for key" sounds like you ran the code twice, and it uses a database and already has some data you try to insert. Clean up or recreate the database, or pick a different key. If that doesn't fix it, please [edit] your question and fix your code's indentation so that people can reproduce the issue. See [ask].

Comment: error has been solved 
mistake 
in order_details table the order_id column was foreign key  as well as primary key
solution
in order_details table remove the order_id column from primary key